# Will the sequence ever change?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Here is a sequence that seems to go on forever. Will it? Will this sequence ever change?

1,2,3,1,0,1,2,3,1,0,1,2,3,1,0  and so on

What does this sequence relate to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sequence is generated by:

> counting the **number of 'I's** that appear in the **Roman numeral representation** of the natural numbers 1, 2, 3, ...
>
>  So, for example, the numbers given in the puzzle relate to the terms:
>
>  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
>
>  which in Roman numerals are represented as:
>
>  **I**, **II**, **III**, **I**V, V, V**I**, V**II**, V**III**, **I**X, X, X**I**, X**II**, X**III**, X**I**V, XV
>
>  where you can clearly see the pattern:
>
>  1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0
>
>  when you count the number of I's.

As to whether this sequence might go on forever...

> Strictly speaking, if applying the construction rules of Roman numerals using the main 7 characters 'I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D' and 'M' it is only possible to create numbers up to a value of 3,999 (MMMCMXCIX), since there is no way to construct a value for '4000' using only these characters. (And so this sequence is terminated after 3999 terms, with the same 1-2-3-1-0 pattern appearing 799 times in a row, culminating in a final 1-2-3-1.)
>
>  If, however, we use the common convention that a numeral with a bar above it represents a multiple of 1000 (i.e. $\bar{I}$ for 1000, $\bar{V}$ for 5000, etc.) then this wouldn't be a lot of help either, as using $\overline{IV}$ to try and continue the sequence to 4000 would produce an 'I' character in a place where there should be none if the sequence were to continue as originally...

Comment: This is in the OEIS as [A278313](https://oeis.org/A278313).